# Kafka Streams Exactly Once Consumer Groups

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

When I turn on exactly once processing I get the following error.  NOTE:  Our application are very secure and we only give kafka users and consumers access to resources that they explicitly need.

```
2019-04-22 15:28:09 INFO  (kafka.authorizer.logger)233 - Principal = User:xxx is Denied Operation = Describe from hos
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx on resource = TransactionalId:application_consumer-0_16
```

With exactly once processing does kafka streams use a consumer group per stream task instead of a consumer group across all stream tasks?

Answer (score 0):

With exactly-once enabled, there is still only one consumer group that is the same as the `application.id`. However, instead of using one `Producer` per thread, one producer per *task* is used.

What you need is permission for transaction. The `TransactionsId` the error reports is from the producer of task `0_16`. Each producer uses its own transactional ID, that is constructed as `<application.id>-<taskId>`.

For details, compare the docs: https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authorization.html#using-acls

Comment: And also for Kafka Streams security specifically: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/security.html#required-acl-setting-for-secure-ak-clusters